# Best way to estimate a regression with reaction times

Tags: regression, data-visualization, spss, generalized-linear-model, logarithm

I have reactions times in a no-normal distribution, so I am using logarithms.
Which can be the best way to estimate a regression?
Later, I would like to plot the results according to the age of my subjects.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I removed your signature, as it is automatically added. What is it you are trying to do? It seems like reaction times are the dependent variable and age an independent variable, is that right? Do you  have other IVs?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that´s right. I have reactions times as dependent variables. My IV will be age in the first analysis and condition (sick or healthy control) in the other. I am using repeated measures (2 RTs in 2 blocks)
I would like to plot the regression according to age.

Thanks again

Yacila

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in the relationship between reaction time and 1) age 2) condition. You have two repeats of reaction time.

The first thing is that there is no need to run a separate regression for each independent variable. You can include them both in one regression, and usually this is more appropriate than separate regressions.  You might also want to include the interaction.

Next, before running any regressions I would plot the data. Make scatter plots of all variables against each other. Make a plot of the DV against each IV, controlling for the other IV (there are various ways to do this, in `R` there are tools to do it in both `lattice` and `ggplot2`; in `SAS` you can do it with `SGPLOT`).

Then you have to think about  what to do about repeated measures. Why have you got two repeats? What to do about them will depend partly on the answer to this.

After all that you are ready to model. It may be a regression, it may be a multilevel model. OLS regression makes no assumption about the distribution of the DV or IV (only that the DV is continuous) but it does make assumptions about the residuals. So, after a regression you will want to check these. However, BEFORE the regression you might think about a transformation of time; it might be worth considering the inverse of time: This changes reaction time into reaction rate, and that may make more sense as a DV.